# How do I clean up this code and Make it Loop back to the Options Menu/beginning?

Tags: python

```
print("Options:")
print("[P] Print Options")
print("[C] Convert from Celsius")
print("[F] Convert from Fahrenheit")
print("[M] Convert from Miles")
print("[KM] Convert from Kilometers")
print("[In] Convert from Inches")
print("[CM] Convert from Centimeters")
print("[Q] Quit")
Option1 = input("Option: ")

if Option1 == "C":
  Celsius = int(input("Celsius Temperature: "))
  F1 = float(Celsius*9//5 +32)
  print("Fahrenheit: " + str(F1))

elif Option1 == "F":
  Fahrenheit = int(input("Fahrenheit Temperature: "))
  C1 = float((Fahrenheit-32)*5//9)
  print("Celcius: " + str(C1))

elif Option1 == "M":
  Miles = int(input("Miles Distance: "))
  M1 = float((Miles//1.609))
  print("Kilometers: " + str(M1))

elif Option1 == "KM":
  Kilometers = int(input("Kilometers Distance: "))
  KM1 = float((Kilometers*1.609))
  print("Miles: " + str(KM1))

elif Option1 == "In":
  Inches = int(input("Inches: "))
  In = float((Inches*2.54))
  print("Centimeters: " + str(In))

elif Option1 == "CM":
  Centimeters = float(input("Centimeters: "))
  CM1 = float((Centimeters//2.54))
  print("Inches: " + str(CM1))

elif Option1 == "Y":
  Yard = float(input("Yard: "))
  Y1 = float((Yard//1.094))
  print("Meters: " + str(Y1))

elif Option1 == "MT":
  Meters = float(input("Meters: "))
  MT1 = float((Meters*1.094))
  print("Yard: " + str(MT1))
```

How do I clean up this code and Make it Loop back to the Options Menu/beginning? I am o design a simple computer program to help convert from Metric to SI
units anything you all do at CSA which uses the same system as any other commonwealth
country.
You design a Program to come up with a software to convert:

1. Temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius and back
2. Convert Nautical Miles to KMS and back,
3. Convert Kilometer to Miles and back,
4. Convert Centimeters to meters and back
5. Convert Yard to Meters and back,
6. Convert Inches to Centimeters and back
   Your program should be menu driven with Options to pick from the running program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop

```py
print("Options:")
print("[P] Print Options")
print("[C] Convert from Celsius")
print("[F] Convert from Fahrenheit")
print("[M] Convert from Miles")
print("[KM] Convert from Kilometers")
print("[In] Convert from Inches")
print("[CM] Convert from Centimeters")
print("[Q] Quit")
while True:
    Option1 = input("Option: ")

    if Option1 == "C":
        Celsius = int(input("Celsius Temperature: "))
        F1 = float(Celsius*9//5 +32)
        print("Fahrenheit: " + str(F1))

    elif Option1 == "F":
        Fahrenheit = int(input("Fahrenheit Temperature: "))
        C1 = float((Fahrenheit-32)*5//9)
        print("Celcius: " + str(C1))

    elif Option1 == "M":
        Miles = int(input("Miles Distance: "))
        M1 = float((Miles//1.609))
        print("Kilometers: " + str(M1))

    elif Option1 == "KM":
        Kilometers = int(input("Kilometers Distance: "))
        KM1 = float((Kilometers*1.609))
        print("Miles: " + str(KM1))

    elif Option1 == "In":
        Inches = int(input("Inches: "))
        In = float((Inches*2.54))
        print("Centimeters: " + str(In))

    elif Option1 == "CM":
        Centimeters = float(input("Centimeters: "))
        CM1 = float((Centimeters//2.54))
        print("Inches: " + str(CM1))

    elif Option1 == "Y":
        Yard = float(input("Yard: "))
        Y1 = float((Yard//1.094))
        print("Meters: " + str(Y1))

    elif Option1 == "MT":
        Meters = float(input("Meters: "))
        MT1 = float((Meters*1.094))
        print("Yard: " + str(MT1))
```

You can read more about `while loop` [here](http://www.easypythondocs.com/while.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simplify your code by defining one dictionary and use values from that dictionary.

You can also use while loop for continuous input check the below sample example,

you can add more operation(options) in dictionary in similar way:

```
print("Options:")
print("[P] Print Options")
print("[C] Convert from Celsius")
print("[F] Convert from Fahrenheit")
print("[M] Convert from Miles")
print("[KM] Convert from Kilometers")
print("[In] Convert from Inches")
print("[CM] Convert from Centimeters")
print("[Q] Quit")
Option1 = ''
while Option1 != 'Q':
    Option1 = input("Option: ")

    operations = {"C":{"message":"Celsius Temperature: ","formula":"float(input_value*9//5 +32)","print":"Fahrenheit: "},
                  "F":{"message":"Fahrenheit Temperature: ","formula":"float((input_value-32)*5//9)","print":"Celcius: "}}

    opt = operations.get(Option1, None)

    if opt:
        input_value = int(input(operations[Option1]['message']))
        out = eval(operations[Option1]['formula'])
        print(operations[Option1]['print'] + str(out))
```